# Making an Interface in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I am learning how to make interfaces in the game engine, and I have set up 2 buttons: an exit button and a play button. When one of the buttons receives a left click, it either closes Blender or goes to another screen with a monkey.

The problem is that both buttons are doing the same stuff at the same time. They're switching scenes and closing the program, and the biggest problem is that I don't have to click on the buttons at all. When testing, I can click anywhere in the Blender and it does this.

Here is [the .blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/33383) if you need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mouse Sensor when set to *Left Button* will send a positive pulse **whenever** the left mouse button is clicked. To get it to trigger only when over a specific object you have to add another Mouse sensor set to *Mouse Over* and plug it in to the same *And* controller as the click sensor. Like in the image below.
[image: logic bricks]