# Problem with movements script in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm pretty new to the bge, which I'm using for a school project and right now I'm having a problem with my movements.py script. I know this question is quite 'noobish' but I just can't find the problem. The 'player' object is just a cube with character physics and actor enabled but **won't move** when I start the game simulation and press the different keys.

```
import bge


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    player = cont.owner

    keyboard = bge.logic.keyboard

    if keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE:
        player.applyMovement((0, .2, 0), True)    

    if keyboard.events[bge.events.SKEY] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE:
        player.applyMovement((0,-.2, 0), True)  

    if keyboard.events[bge.events.AKEY] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE:
        player.applyMovement((-.2, 0, 0), True)

    if keyboard.events[bge.events.DKEY] == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE:
        player.applyMovement((.2, 0, 0), True)

main()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your problem is? "I'm having a problem with my script" does not really tell us anything.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. Edited the question. My character won't move like he should with this script. Nothing happens at all.

Comment: I made a quick scene using your script and the cube move fine. Make sure the Sensor running your script is always running. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv0Cr.png Connect an *Always* sensor to the Python controller and activate **TRUE level triggering**.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about this one. Used BGE like 5 years ago so I couldn't remember small things like this.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: You need to enable [True Level Triggering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/sensors/common_options.html).

#### By default the "*Always*" Sensor only runs once, when game starts.

Any time you need something "always" triggered then you **must** click the little button with the three dots on the right side of the "*Always*" Sensor called "*True Level Triggering*" (I have it marked in red in the image below).
[image: Always sensor and Python controller]

So your script works fine, just it was not running during the game.