# Changing colors for BGE

Tags: materials, game-engine, logic-bricks

I want my games that have function that can changes the character colors.I have try [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21423/how-to-change-materials-color-in-blender-game-engine) a few times.I can make it changes colors in the menu but the colors doesnt change when I click start button. Can any body help me please.

Comment: what does your game do "when I click start button" Sounds like you are probably changing scenes, and you did not change the color of the car in that scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways to change object colors in real time: through *Object Color* material's option, or through material node's *Hue/Saturation* (available in realtime only in [UPBGE](https://upbge.org/)).

## Object Color

This one is pretty simple:

- Enable the *Object Color* checkbox on the desired material.
- Change the *Object Color* in realtime by animating it.

[image]

Example file: [image]

## Hue/Saturation Node

This one is a bit more complex, but a lot more powerful and with better results. Remember this one **ONLY** is possible in realtime on [UPBGE](https://upbge.org/).

- Go to *Node Editor* and enable the node compositing for the desired material.
- Add an *Hue/Saturation* node between the *Material* node and the *Output* node.
- Separate the RGB colors of the object and set the hue value to the red value.
- Animate the red color on *Object Color* to change the hue in realtime.

[image]

Example file: [image]

Comment: It works but only at the menu.After I change the color,when I click start button,It still the same