# How to change diffuse color in UPBGE real time

Tags: python, materials, game-engine

I have two materials assigned to an object. I checked both materials in Material> Options> Object Color. I want to change one of the materials without affecting the other material in real time. It's similar to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21423/how-to-change-materials-color-in-blender-game-engine), but this time it's more than one material.

```py
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
obj = cont.owner

# Material no. 1
obj.color = [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

# Material no. 2
obj.color = [ 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1.0]
```

My goal here exactly is that I have 2 color palettes alongside with 2 materials assigned for a 1 object.

Comment: Blender doesn't have a game engine nowadays. It was forked off to https://upbge.org/ some while ago so I suggest you look at the [documentation](https://upbge.org/#/documentation) there.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is UPBGE.

Comment: Questions about UPBGE are off-topic here.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for letting me know.